# Maps circle to "edge" of square region

Tags: general-topology

I was read a book and then I try to solve this problem:

The map that sends the interval in $S^1$ from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ onto the intervals in the square from $y_i$ to $y_{i+1}$ defines a homeomorphism from the circle to the square.

[image]

If $\{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ is the circle and $\{ (x,y) : x = \pm 1, -1 \leq y \leq 1 \text{ or } -1 \leq x \leq 1, y = \pm 1 \}$ is the square then explicit homeomorphism are givem by

circle $\to$ square

$(x,y) \to (x/m, y/m)$

and

square $\to$ circle

$(x,y) \to (x/r, y/r)$

where $m = \max (|x|,|y|)$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Intuitively we just twist or bend circle to square.

In first try to construct these maps, I used the trigonometric fuctions (like https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344 , page 8), but this is not that problem do. My question is, how can I construct the map of circle to square and square to circle using the problem information?

Thanks.

Comment: The formulas are given. What are you missing ?

Comment: How to get these formulas. For example, how  can I get these from circle and square equations? For example, I think that, if I use the lines y=x and y=-x I can map the top of square to circle in region that y>x, but I can not think more than this. So I need the metod to construct the equations circle to square and square to circle

Comment: The formulas are given. What more do you want ?

Comment: I simple way to squaring the disk, using those information, maps x_1 and x_2 to y_1 and y_2 and so on, and at the end you get the given formulas

Comment: Hem, for the last time, the formulas are known, you posted them.

Answer (score 1):

You already have explicit homeomorphisms that work.

Let me be somewhat more general and denote $\|(x,y)\|_\infty=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$ and $\|(x,y)\|_2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then closed disk is described as $\{x\in\Bbb R^2\,|\, \|x\|_2\leq 1\}$ and circle as $\{x\in\Bbb R^2\,|\, \|x\|_2=1\}$, while closed square as $\{x\in\Bbb R^2\,|\, \|x\|_\infty\leq1\}$ and its boundary is $\{x\in\Bbb R^2\,|\, \|x\|_\infty=1\}$. Your maps can be written as
$$x\mapsto x/\|x\|_\infty,\quad x\mapsto x/\|x\|_2$$

Quick check shows that $\|x/\|x\|_\infty\|_\infty = 1$ and $\|x/\|x\|_2\|_2 = 1$ so these really do map circle to boundary of square and vice versa.

More generally, you can consider mapping whole disk to square and square to disk. In that case you would define maps with:

$$x\mapsto\frac {\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty}x,\quad x\mapsto \frac {\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2}x $$

*(except at $x=0$ where this is not well defined - extend them by sending $0$ to $0$ in both cases)*

Now, for $\|x\|_2\leq 1$ you have $$\left\|\frac {\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty}x\right\|_\infty = \|x\|_2 \leq 1$$ and for $\|x\|_\infty\leq 1$ you have $$\left\|\frac {\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2}x\right\|_2 = \|x\|_\infty \leq 1$$ so everything checks out.

If you restrict those maps to boundaries, you will get your original maps: for $\|x\|_2 = 1$, $\frac {\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty}x = x/\|x\|_\infty$ and similarly for $\|x\|_\infty = 1$.

What these maps do is scale appropriate vectors. Make sure that you understand why both are continuous and confirm that they are inverses.

Comment: @brunob, seems that I've been mislead by your title. You want boundaries of disk and square, right? Note that these are not open sets. In that case, your maps are good and what I've written simplifies to your maps (i.e., they send boundaries to bondaries).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want only the boundaries. I correct (tried) the title, sorry for my mistake, thanks.